# Data is not passed to the NVD3Chart

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nvd3.js

I am new to both `React` and `NVD3`. I am trying to render an index page that has `React` and `NVD3` but somehow data is not passed to the `NVD3Chart`. I am rendering it with `node`. The `index.jsx` file looks the following way:

```
import React from 'react';
import DefaultLayout from './layouts/default';
import NVD3Chart from 'react-nvd3';

// JSON data
import datum from './datum'

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DefaultLayout title={this.props.title}>
        <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>
        <NVD3Chart id="barChart" type="discreteBarChart" datum={datum}   
x="label" y="value"/>
      </DefaultLayout>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = App;
```

The page is rendering fine, no errors are printed out. The `datum` is also fine: I did `console.log(datum)` in `render()` and also printed out on webpage.

I tried supplying the data inline to the `NVD3Chart` tag, but the result is the same, no rendering happens:

```
<NVD3Chart id="barChart" type="discreteBarChart" datum='[{
      key: "Cumulative Return",
      values: [
        {
          "label" : "A" ,
          "value" : -29.765957771107
        } ,
        {
          "label" : "B" ,
          "value" : 0
        } ,
        {
          "label" : "C" ,
          "value" : 32.807804682612
        } ,
        {
          "label" : "D" ,
          "value" : 196.45946739256
        } ,
        {
          "label" : "E" ,
          "value" : 0.19434030906893
        } ,
        {
          "label" : "F" ,
          "value" : -98.079782601442
        } ,
        {
          "label" : "G" ,
          "value" : -13.925743130903
        } ,
        {
          "label" : "H" ,
          "value" : -5.1387322875705
        }
      ]
    }
  ]' x="label" y="value"/>
```

If I go to the Developers Console and see html, it looks the following way:

[image]

I tried `import * as d3 from "d3";` at the top thinking of maybe `nvd3-react` needs also `d3` import, but no success.

Why is it not working? What could I try?